# How to get titles of next and previous pages on current page using pager in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, pager

How to get the titles of the next and previous pages below next and previous links on current page using mini pager or any other techniques in Drupal 8 ?

Comment: The item array which contain next and previous objects doesn't give titles.

Comment: It gives you an url ? a path ? or a nid ? if you have one of these thing you cant load node and get title with sql or drupal function ;)

Comment: It gives an url. I'll check if I can load and get the title with sql or drupal function

Comment: you can retrieve information by url in alias table , get source , and then get nid